# работа скрипта на разных серверах

Tags: php, mysql, сервер, mysqli, hosting

Имеется скрипт:

```html
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 
<?php
$mysqli =mysqli_connect('---', '---', '---', '---');
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM climat');
  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'date', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 't_in', 'type' => 'number')
);
     foreach($result as $r) {
 
     $temp = array();
     $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['date']); 
     $temp[] = array('v' => (float) $r['t_in']); 
     $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }
 
$table['rows'] = $rows;

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

На одном сервере с PHP Version 5.6.11, mysql 5.6.27  работает.
А на другом сервере с PHP Version 5.3.21, mysql 5.5.28  не работает.
Не выводятся данные.

Каким образом можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: А в базе точно есть данные, которые он должен выводить

Comment: А почему должно работать `$mysqli->query` если у вас коннект идет через процедурный стиль а не через объектный. видимо 5.6 хавает такие конструкции... Может в этом дело? http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Answer (score 1):

@АлексейШиманский прав, нужно определиться при выборе процедурного или объектного(рекомендую) стиля.

Ниже показан коннект(из мануала), а остальное перепишете сами с помощью [мануала](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php).

P.S. Чтобы было ясно о чем речь - код нужно привести в такой вид:

вместо `$r['date']` -> `$r->date` и т.д.

```
# Сам коннект
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Ошибка подключения (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```